# How to use event handlers with "update" function to start and stop a stopwatch

Tags: javascript, html, button, event-handling, stopwatch

I need to attach the event handlers to the update function so that the stop button will stop the time and the start button will start it again.

I have tried multiple ways of doing this, shown by the function handlers. But I cannot seem to get this to work.

```js
stop = document.getElementById('Stop');
        var watchRunning = new Boolean(false);

        Start.addEventListener('click', startHandler);

        function startHandler() {
            d.watchRunning = true;
        }

        Stop.addEventListener('click', stopHandler);

        function stopHandler() {
            stop.onclick = function() {
                clearTimeout(watchRunning);
            }
        }

        update();
        var testVar = window.setInterval(update, 10);
        var seconds;
        var milliseconds;
        var d;

        function update() {
            d = new Date();
            seconds = d.getSeconds();
            milliseconds = Math.floor((d.getMilliseconds() / 10));

            if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    "0" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds >= 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    seconds + ":0" + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds < 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    "0" + seconds + ":" + milliseconds;

            } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds >= 10) {
                document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
                    seconds + ":" + milliseconds;
            }
        }
```

```css
#Time {
            background-color: yellow;
            max-width: 5%;
        }
```

```html
<h1>Stop Watch</h1>
    <button id="Start">Start</button>
    <button id="Stop">Stop</button>
    <h3>Elapsed Time:</h3>
    <p id="Time"></p>
```

Is there anything  can do to make these work? Where would I need to update my update function? Any tips help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to subtract time, here's what you can do.

1. On start, write down the current time.
2. On update, see how much time has passed since we last wrote it down, add it to the total time passed, write down the current time again.
3. On stop, stop updating the timer.

Spoiler:

```js
const stop = document.getElementById('Stop');
const start = document.getElementById('Start');
let watchIntervalTimer;
let countingSince;

function startHandler() {
    if (!watchIntervalTimer) {  // If it's not set.
        watchIntervalTimer = setInterval(updateTimer, 10);
        countingSince = Date.now();
    }
}

function stopHandler() {
    clearInterval(watchIntervalTimer);
    watchIntervalTimer = null;  // So we can identify that it's reset.
}

Start.addEventListener('click', startHandler);
Stop.addEventListener('click', stopHandler);

var seconds;
var milliseconds;
var d;
let timePassed = 0;
updateLabel();

function updateTimer() {
    timePassed += Date.now() - countingSince;
    countingSince = Date.now();
    updateLabel();
}

function updateLabel() {
    d = new Date(timePassed);
    seconds = d.getSeconds();
    milliseconds = Math.floor((d.getMilliseconds() / 10));

    if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds < 10) {
        document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
            "0" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds;

    } else if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds >= 10) {
        document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
            seconds + ":0" + milliseconds;

    } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds < 10) {
        document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
            "0" + seconds + ":" + milliseconds;

    } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds >= 10) {
        document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
            seconds + ":" + milliseconds;
    }
}
```

```css
#Time {
    background-color: yellow;
    max-width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Stop Watch</h1>
<button id="Start">Start</button>
<button id="Stop">Stop</button>
<h3>Elapsed Time:</h3>
<p id="Time"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what I'd do is just `setInterval` when the "Start" is pressed, if it's not already set; and `clearInterval` on "Stop".
Spoiler:

```js
const stop = document.getElementById('Stop');
const start = document.getElementById('Start');
let watchIntervalTimer;

function startHandler() {
    if (!watchIntervalTimer) {  // If it's not set.
        watchIntervalTimer = setInterval(update, 10);
    }
}

function stopHandler() {
    clearInterval(watchIntervalTimer);
    watchIntervalTimer = null;  // So we can identify that it's reset.
}

Start.addEventListener('click', startHandler);
Stop.addEventListener('click', stopHandler);

update();
var seconds;
var milliseconds;
var d;

function update() {
    d = new Date();
    seconds = d.getSeconds();
    milliseconds = Math.floor((d.getMilliseconds() / 10));

    if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds < 10) {
        document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
            "0" + seconds + ":0" + milliseconds;

    } else if (milliseconds < 10 && seconds >= 10) {
        document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
            seconds + ":0" + milliseconds;

    } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds < 10) {
        document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
            "0" + seconds + ":" + milliseconds;

    } else if (milliseconds >= 0 && seconds >= 10) {
        document.getElementById("Time").innerHTML =
            seconds + ":" + milliseconds;
    }
}
```

```css
#Time {
    background-color: yellow;
    max-width: 5%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Stop Watch</h1>
<button id="Start">Start</button>
<button id="Stop">Stop</button>
<h3>Elapsed Time:</h3>
<p id="Time"></p>
```

Comment: When I click stop, it stops fine. But then when I click start again, it starts from a different time. Almost as if the time is still going, only the animation stops when "stop" is clicked.

Comment: Could you explain why that is?

Comment: `d = new Date();` On each update, you're getting the current system time.

To prevent this, you can create your own variable and add 10 (milliseconds) to it on each `update()` call.
Then, to conver milliseconds to time, you can use `setMilliseconds` on a `Date` object (which you can initialize with `new Date(0)`.

Comment: Is there any way to define a variable with "new Date()" before the update function. Then inside of the update function subtract the previous "new Date()" and the current "new Date()"?     Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Well, yes. You can remember the current time each time you start the timer and subtract it from the current time on each update.

Comment: Can you possibly guide me on how to do that? I haven't been able to do it successfully after trying many times.

Comment: Added as a new answer.